# How to calculate the probability of winning a lottery.

Tags: probability, combinations

In a certain lottery 10,000 tickets are sold and ten equal prizes are awarded.
What is the probability of **not getting a prize** if you buy:

(a)One ticket

(b)two tickets

(c)ten tickets

Comment: if 1 ticket=1 prize, the probability of winning a prize with 1 ticket is $p_s = \frac{1}{1000}$. Can you handle the rest of the problem?

Comment: @alex Sir $1 ticket \not= 1$ prize, there are 10 prizes out of 10,000 tickets.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you've tried already so we know what specifically to help you with

Comment: @LoganTatham Sir I have no idea of how to approach to these kind of problems, so it would be helpful for me if you provide the approach and explain how to handle these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $9990$ non-winning tickets so the probability of not winning any of the prizes with $n$ tickets is

$$P(n) = \prod_0^{n-1} \frac{9990 - n}{10000 - n}.$$

So calculate this for $n=1, 2, 10$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with John's answer, for $n$ being a small number of tickets, the probability of not winning any prize can be approximated as a Taylor series built around $n=0$. This gives, as an approximation  $$P(n)=1 - 1.00045*10^{-3} n + 4.50405*10^{-7} n^2$$ For $n=100$, the exact value is $0.904341$ while the approximation gives $0.904459$.

Using John's formula, if you want $P(n)=0.5$, you need to buy $669$ tickets